# Files windows close when documents opened within them close

Tags: nautilus, files, libreoffice

I am getting strange behavior with Files/nautilus windows. If I open a document—I mostly notice this with LibreOffice documents—within a Files window by double clicking on it, and do some work, and then close that document using a keyboard shortcut **the Files window also closes.** This is annoying as I am constantly having to open new Files windows and re-navigate to some directory I am working in.

Is window focus somehow being shared between LibreOffice and Files? Why is this happening, and how can I make it stop?

I am using Ubuntu 18.10, Unity, and gdm3.

Edited to add details based on comments:

- I have set "Close" in LibreOffice to ALT+W.
- ALT+SPACEBAR C does not close my LibreOffice documents or my Files windows.
- ALT+F4 does not "close window" but "quits program," so seems unrelated to the issue at hand.

Comment: I can't duplicate this on my system.  Which keyboard shortcut are you using to close the document?

Comment: @CharlesGreen I have set "Close" in LibreOffice to ALT+W.

Comment: Interesting - I suppose that is easier to reach than Atl+f4, or Ctrl-Q?  How did you set Alt+w to be the close command?

Comment: @CharlesGreen Tools > Customize allows all the menu options, plus macros, plus many non-menu options to be tied to specific accelerators.

Comment: I only tested with alt+f4 and ctrl-Q, neither of which is customizable, apparently.  Do you have the same behavior if you use one of those?

Comment: Do you see the same behavior if you *don't* use `Alt+W` but use `Alt+F4` or `Alt+spacebar` followed by `C` instead?

Comment: @Lexible, add the info you supply in the comments to the question. Personally, I cannot reproduce this behavior assigning "Document - close" to Alt+w. nautilus stays open. Might therefore be related to Unity.